# How can I mock the singleton object (scala 2.7.11)?

Tags: scala, mockito, powermock, scalatest, scalamock

I want to mock the singleton object?
It seems that it's impossible in scalamock-3

I found that easyMock and powerMock can mock the singleton object 
(from https://github.com/fabura/scala-MockStaticObjects)

However, I cant get this work?
Any ideas?

Comment: why do you need that? what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a database singleton object, and I want to mock this database manager.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create a trait which describes db operation and implement this trait in the singleton object? Thus you can mock just this trait

Comment: Did you really mean scala 2.7.11? That's absolutely ancient and it's going to severely restrict what you can do with the language and ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

If the singleton object has a static .getInstance method, it is fairly easy to mock.

You need to do the following 
at the top of your test class

`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest(Singleton.class)`

then to mock the singleton

`mockStatic(Singleton.class);
Singleton mockSingleton = mock(Singleton.class);
when(Singleton.getInstance()).thenReturn(mockSingleton);`

any values you want to have the returned singleton to have I believe you have to set prior to the "when" Example: `when(mockSingleton.toString()).thenReturn("I'm a mock");`